# Can I add a component in a method call inside a Vueitfy Calendar to display an icon on an event?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a calendar set-up that uses a method to get the name of the event:

```
        <v-calendar
          ref="calendar"
          :events="day_reports"
          :event-name="formatEventName"
        ></v-calendar>
```

The method looks like this:

```
      formatEventName(event) {
        let icon = // how do I render a v-btn component here?
        return icon + event.input.user.name
      },
```

Any idea how can dynamically insert a v-btn element here?

Answer (score 0):

To format the event name you could use the [`event`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-calendar/#slots-event) slot instead of `event-name` prop :

```
<v-calendar
          ref="calendar"
          :events="day_reports"
          :event-name="formatEventName"
        >
  <template #event="{eventParsed}" >
      <v-btn><v-icon>icon_name</v-icon> {{eventParsed.input.user.name}}<v-btn>
  </template>

</v-calendar>
```